# Add two string arrays to dictionary

Tags: vb.net

I want to merge two string arrays in a Dictionary

I tried this:

```
Dim array1() As String = {"A","B"}
Dim array2() As String = {"a","b"}
Dim Dict As Dictionary(Of String, String)
For i = 0 To array1.Count() - 1
   Dict.Add(array1(i), array2(i))
Next
```

but i got Null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim array1() As String = {"A","B"}
Dim array2() As String = {"a","b"}
Dim Dict As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
For i = 0 To array1.Count() - 1
   Dict.Add(array1(i), array2(i))
Next
```

You don't New the Dictionary, i.e. no object to work with.